# How to update a record from database via ADO.NET Entity Framework?

Tags: wpf, database, entity-framework

My WPF desktop-based application uses ADO.Net Entity Framework in order to connect to SQL Server database. In one of the windows I have a `DataGrid` with all data from `tbl_users`, when user selects one of the rows (records) and clicks on *Edit*, application opens a new window with form, that includes all data that user can edit/update.

How to save changes (update/edit) of one of the table's values to database via ADO.NET Entity Framework?

Here are some code snippets that help understand a situation:

1 - Edit window constructor

```
public object objToBeEdited;

public WinWorkers_EditWorker(tbl_users userToBeEdited){
    this.Title = Glidus.Properties.Resources.WinWorkers_EditWorker_WinName + Glidus.Properties.Resources.WinApp_WinName;
}
```

2 - Method Update, that doesn't work

```
//assume inputted values to new object
tbl_users newUser = new tbl_users() {
    userName = this.WinWorkers_AddEditWorkers_Form_UserName.Text,
    userPassword = this.WinWorkers_AddEditWorkers_Form_Password.Text,
    userAccessLevel = this.WinWorkers_AddEditWorkers_Form_UserAccessLevel.Text
};

//default minimal password length is 4
if (App.IsInputValueMinLenOK(newUser.userPassword, 4)) {

    EntityKey key = App.glidusContext.CreateEntityKey("tbl_users", objToBeEdited);

    if (App.glidusContext.TryGetObjectByKey(key, out objToBeEdited)) {
        App.glidusContext.ApplyCurrentValues<tbl_users>(key.EntitySetName, newUser);
    }

    try {
        App.glidusContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        App.UnitedHandleException(ex);
    }
}
```

Please, help me, how to implement update ADO.NET record from the database. For example, in my table there is *James Bond 007*, after editing page (clicking in submit page) I see *Austin Powers 008*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To edit or update you can use [stub entities](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/19/tip-26-how-to-avoid-database-queries-using-stub-entities.aspx)

```
Category category = new Category { ID = 5};
Context.AttachTo(“Categories”,category);

Product product = new Product {
     Name = “Bovril”,
     Category = category
};
Context.AddToProducts(product);
Context.SaveChanges();
```